# problem with php function error

Tags: php, errors

Hi I seem to get this message

> ```
> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\knowledgepress\lib\ticket-functions.php on line 851
> ```

However looking at the code I cant see a problem?

```
if (!function_exists('woo_supportpress_get_ticket_details')) {
    function woo_supportpress_get_ticket_details( $post_id ) { 

        $status = current(wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'ticket_status' ));
        $type = current(wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'ticket_type' ));
        $priority = current(wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'ticket_priority' ));

        if (!isset($status->name)) $status = '';

        if (!isset($type->name)) $type = '';

        if (!isset($priority->name)) $priority = '';

        $ticket_details = array(
            'status' => $status
            ,'type' => $type
            ,'priority' => $priority
            ,'assigned_to' => get_user_by('id', get_post_meta( $post_id, '_responsible', true))
            ,'reported_by' => get_post_meta( $post_id, '_reported_by', true)
            ,'reported_by_email' => get_post_meta( $post_id, '_reported_by_email', true)
        );

        /* Support 'Anybody' user */
        if (!isset($ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name)) $ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name = 'Anybody';
        if (!isset($ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID)) $ticket_details['assigned_to']->ID = 0;

        return $ticket_details;

    }
}
```

line 851:

```
if (!isset($ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name)) $ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name = 'Anybody'; '
```

Comment: Which one is line 851?

Comment: get_user_by() returns false if no user is found, so no object exists for $ticket_details['assigned_to'] I'm guessing.  Try just checking for if( !$ticket_details['assigned_to'] )

Comment: Please clarify how this question is **WordPress**-specific.

Answer (score 1):

When `$ticket_details['assigned_to']->display_name` is not set, `get_user_by()` has returned not an object but `FALSE`.

First test if you got an object:

```
$user = get_user_by('id', get_post_meta( $post_id, '_responsible', true));

if ( ! is_object( $user ) )
    return;

$ticket_details['assigned_to'] = $user;
```

`display_name` is always set if there is an user object. At least to an empty string.

Comment: @user31891 See my update.

Comment: sorry this is removing the error but assigned to disappears on the custom post type

Comment: to resolve the problem i rolled back to php 5.3.13